# RRD - How to bypass the limitation of MIN and MAX RRAs being NaN for non consolidated CDPs

Tags: graph, rrdtool, rrd

Let's say I have a RRD with 3 data sources: `rtt_min`, `rtt_avg` and `rtt_max` storing data from network packet round trip time tests. Explanation of each DS is somewhat obvious:

- `rtt_min` is a minimum value of all RTT times during a single test.
- `rtt_avg` is a average value of all RTT times during a single test.
- `rtt_max` is a maximum value of all RTT times during a single test.

These tree float values are stored in RRD file after each test (assume the frequency is the same as RRD step value). My goal is to graph the `rtt_avg` value and also `rtt_min` and `rtt_max` as a boundary values. There are two obvious scenarios:

1. I can graph `AVERAGE` for each DS which would produce accurate results for RRAs where each row has one PDP (1CDP = 1PDP; latest data with no consolidation). But for old data, average values for `rtt_min` and `rtt_max` would not be what I want, as i need to graph minimum and maximum values for those two data sources and `AVERAGE` function is not the best one for it.
2. I can graph `rtt_min:MIN`, `rtt_avg:AVERAGE` and `rtt_max:MAX` which would behave as i want for consolidated (old) data, graphing the minimum, average and maximum DS values for consolidated interval, but would provide low resolution data for latest data for `rtt_min` and `rtt_max`. This is because `MIN` and `MAX` CDPs are `NaN` in 1PDP RRAs. Only after consolidation these CDPs have a value, but using them gives lower resolution data as there are multiple PDPs for each CDP. And those two would look strange alongside the `rtt_avg` which is higher resolution.

I need the combination of both. Since `MIN` and `MAX` are `NaN` for 1PDP RRAs, is there an easy way to graph `rtt_max:LAST` for the period there are data in `LAST`, and for older data to use `rtt_max:MAX`? The only solution i can think of right now is to somehow calculate the time for which we have data in `LAST` and to graph `MAX` before that time and `LAST` after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can graph rtt_min:MIN, rtt_avg:AVERAGE and rtt_max:MAX which would behave as i want

This is what you should do; use a different CF for the MIN and MAX types.

> but would provide low resolution data for latest data for rtt_min and rtt_max.
> This is because MIN and MAX CDPs are NaN in 1PDP RRAs.

This should not be the case.  For a 1PDP RRA, MIN and MAX should give the same result as AVERAGE.  The only reason I can think that this may be happening is that you have misdefined your RRAs or DSs with incorrect xff or heartbeat.

Without the definition of your RRD I cannot be certain but I would imagine this to be the case.  In the past, I have used MAX and MIN on a 1pdp-RRA without issue.

One potential problem is that sometimes the very last value in the RRA is unknown (NaN) because it is not set until that timeslot has completely passed and a new data sample received.  In the past, I have retrieved the last update time for the RRD and used that as the graph base time rather than 'now' to avoid this.  If your update frequency is relatively small then this should not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve for confirming that `MIN`, `MAX`, and `AVERAGE` should be the same for 1PDP RRAs! I double checked the `MIN` and `MAX` data and my claim that it only had `NaN` values for 1PDP RRAs was incorrect. The problem was in RRD definition - the number of rows for `AVERAGE`, `MIN` and `MAX` wasn't the same. `AVERAGE` had 3 times more PDPs resulting in higher resolution for that CF when looking at longer time frames. Unfortunately I missed that because I was given the existing RRD and made some wrong assumptions :)